# What would be necessary to code the callback function to receive the access token?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axosoft

I am trying to retrieve the access token from an API (https://github.com/Axosoft/node-axosoft/)

To receive an access token we have to follow this process:

```
var axo = nodeAxosoft(axosoftUrl, credentials);

axo.Api.getLoginUrl(function(url) {

    // open browser using authorizationUrl and get code parameter from 
   //redirected Url after login

     var code = 'code received from redirect';
     axo.Api.exchangeCodeForToken(code);
 });
```

As I did not understood exactly how to get the code following that example nor what is the url parameter on getLoginUrl, I did it on my own.

I have a login route that redirects the user to the axosoft website for authentication and redirects the user to the /authorization-process route on my application.

On the /authorization-process I get the code returned by the login and call a function that should get the access token by calling:

```
         axo.Api.exchangeCodeForToken(code);
```

Code:

```
var axosoft_code = req.query.code;

  console.log(axosoft_code);

     var token = request.exchangeAuthCodeForAccessToken(axosoft_code)
    .then(function(token)
    {
       res.send(token);
    })
```

The Method:

```
var  connection = nodeAxosoft(client_url, credentials);

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      console.log("CODE: ", axosoft_code)
      var token = connection.Api.exchangeCodeForToken(axosoft_code, function(token){
        console.log(token);
        resolve(token)
      })
```

The problem is that returns `null`

I had a look at the API lib api.js and found that:

https://github.com/Axosoft/node-axosoft/blob/master/lib/api.js

```
function exchangeCodeForToken(code, callback) {
    _credentials.code = code;
    _access_token = '';

    _authenticateCredentails(function (err) {
        if (!err) {
            callback(null, _access_token);
        } else {
            callback(err);
        }
    })
}
```

So I have two questions:

Does anyone has an Idea what am I doing wrong?

What would be necessary to code the callback function?

The method expects a callback function but I don't really know how to do it.

EDIT:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      var token = connection.Api.exchangeCodeForToken(axosoft_code, function(response,err){
        if(!err){
          console.log("token",response)
          resolve(token);
        }
        else{
          console.log("error",err)
          resolve(token);

        }
      });
    })
```

OR

```
var token = connection.Api.exchangeCodeForToken(axosoft_code, function(response,err){
        if(!err){
          console.log("token",response.body)
          return response.body;
        }
        else{
          console.log("error",err)
          return err;
        }
      });
```

I am giving to my callback function two args (response and err), my problem is that I am falling at the else condition.
The output of err is something similar to a token though the documentation [here](http://developer.axosoft.com/authentication/authorization-code.html) shows that it should be like that:

```
{
    "error" : "invalid_request",
    "error_description" : "One or more parameters are missing: client_secret"
}
```

Another point is that the page is frozen waiting for something to happen but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that this is the input:

```
function exchangeCodeForToken(code, callback) {
    _credentials.code = code;
    _access_token = '';

    _authenticateCredentails(function (err) {
        if (!err) {
            callback(null, _access_token);
        } else {
            callback(err);
        }
    })
}
```

You should format your call as:

```
exchangeCodeForToken(axosoft_code, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
        // Deal with error
    } else {
        // Deal with response
    }
}
```

Node functions often pass through error variables first so that you have to receive them, which is considered good practice.

Comment: I had figured that out... thanks anyway.  The explanation you gave me helped a lot as well! Really appreciate.